# for /f is not working in .bat file but it works with command prompt in windows 2003

Tags: command-line, command-prompt, windows-server-2003

**for /f "tokens=1-7 delims=,: " %a in ('query user ^| find /i "disc"') do logoff %b**

This above code is used for logoff remote desktop users where state is "Disconnected" in windows 2003.It will work perfect when I run in command prompt. But it will not run when I made a .bat file or .cmd file in windows 2003.so may know where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside batch files the percent signs used in the `for` replaceable parameters need to be escaped

```dos
for /f "tokens=1-7 delims=,: " %%a in ('query user ^| find /i "disc"') do logoff %%b
```

Comment: no its not working its a 2003 windows server . I tried it.

Comment: @user2503585, How does it not work? What is the observed behaviour?

Comment: its just blinking cmd prompt and disappearing .

Comment: @user2503585, place the command alone inside a batch file, open a `cmd` window and execute the batch file from it. What do you see?

Comment: b was unexpected at this time

Comment: its working fine when i keep that file in c:\windows\system32 but its not working when i place it on desktop

Comment: Thank you very much its working . Issue was path so i set a path got result

Answer (score 2):

User585,

Yes, inorder to implement the for loop inside a bat/cmd session, you need to place the variable with

```
%%a
```

like this

```
for /f %%a in (.\hosts) do quser /server:\\%%a
```